# SQL - Accessing a table by a name which is varchar

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to access a table through its name, which is of varchar data type. The name of the table is stored in a field on another table and I want to be able to get that. For example, say the table name is stored in varchar variable @tablename;

```
SELECT * FROM @tablename
```

general syntax isn't working - is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use dynamic sql to do this

```
DECLARE @SQL varchar(max)
SET @SQL = 'SELECT * FROM '+@tablename

EXEC(@SQL)
```